# Закрывается форма если курсор в текстовом поле при нажатии на Enter

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Сделал простую форму использовал JQuery, Bootstrap, но не понимаю почему если в поле установить курсор, то браузер просто закрывает страницу (( Такая ерунда на всех полях полях формы.

Comment: Покажите хотя бы код. Может у вас на onclick window.close выполняется.

Comment: Спасибо, в этом и была проблема, напиши ответ, сделаю пометку.

Comment: Ого, как попал :)

Comment: Бывает =)) я новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На событие "click" выполняется window.close();